# What is the font used for Latin-American TCM subtitles?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone help me to identify this font? It's used in TCM subtitles for Latin-American TV.

[image]

Thanks so much...

Comment: Check out http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to match fonts.

Comment: If  I post this is because what the font dosn't work, but thanks for the suggest.

Answer (score 2):

WhatTheFont didn't work for me, and it's neither of these, but I can think of two fonts that might help if you are looking for something readable and subtitle-like:

[**Trebuchet**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/microsoft/trebuchet/):

[image]

[**Univers 45**](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFont&code=UNIA10045000):

[image]

Comment: It's neither of these, but Trebuchet is in the ballpark if 'close enough' will work.

Answer (score 2):

It's either [Lucida Sans](http://www.linotype.com/900993/LucidaSansRoman-product.html) or [Optima](http://www.linotype.com/46894/OptimaProMedium-product.html). A lower-case *g* or capital *M* in the example would have clinched it. Lucida's *g* is single-storey; Optima's is two-storey. Optima's *M* is slightly splayed; Lucida's is not.

Lucida Sans:
[image: Lucida Sans example]

Optima:
[image: Optima example]